# How to plot 2D matrix whose data is not equally spaced along x-axis using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, imshow

I am trying to plot a 2D matrix using the matplotlib library (the only one I know so far). However, the function `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(matrix)` presumes that the data is equally spaced along each axis while the data I want to plot is not. My data looks like: the first column of matrix is data on line x=0, the second column's data is on line x=1.27 instead of x=1, and data of third column is on line x=1.42 but not x=2 and so on.

BTW, data is equally spaced along y-axis.

So I'm wondering if there is anyway I can plot this in the way I hope? Thank you for your time and kind help in advance!

------ newbee in Programming

update:
First of all, thank you all for your suggestions! I have tried the methods and here are the outputs:
[image]

This is the graph plotted by `contourf` which is not as I expected. `pcolormesh` doesn't not give an ideal output either.
What I am trying to plot is data of seismic traces which represents the underground structure. I hope to plot something like this:
[image]

If there's any advice on how I can do that, please give me a hint! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that you can try with `pcolor`. It accept two extra arrays for `x` and `y`.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide some data as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the function `pcolormesh`.

You just need to enter the the intervals defined in the 1D arrays x, y and the 2D data, accordingly. Below you find a simple example.

```
from pylab import *
x = logspace(log10(1),log10(100),11)
y = linspace(1,100,21)

data = rand(20,10)
pcolormesh(x,y,data)
show()
```

Notice that x and y have an extra point. In this case, `data` fills up the intervals defined by x and y. Otherwise, you can use the function `contourf`.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You want filled contours ...

- [confourf demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)
- [matplotlib.pyplot.contourf docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf)

The examples should help you get started. Let us know if you have specific problems.